# How to get bing map api credentials

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm doing some testing and noticed that the .getCredentials method the bing map api has is not returning the api key being used. It only return undefined. Is there another way of getting they key with another method? Or do I have to assign the credentials in a certain way to be able to have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

The getCredentials method returns a special key called a session key from the map. This is assuming you specify a key when loading your map. You can use the session key to call other Bing Maps services and have those transactions marked as non-billable, as they would be part of that user session.

If you want to get access to the original credentials, store it in a variable in your code.

Comment: even if I store it in a variable,It would be the same if I am trying to access the credentials directly from the map object.

Comment: No it wouldn't as the map only provides session keys when requesting credentials from the map. Sessions keys are very important and allow you to make calls to other Bing Maps services and have them marked as non-billable in your application as they become part of that map session.